# Dynamically change checkboxes with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have the following checkbox:

```
input(type='checkbox', ng-model='auto', ng-checked='auto', ng-change='save()')
```

As soon as I save it from the method in `ng-change` it save the auto value correctly but the app also listen to SSE (Server Sent Events) to update that value:

A simple example:

```
$scope.$watch(Auto.getNewValue, function (newAutoValue) {
    if (newAutoValue !== null) {
        $scope.auto = newAutoValue;
    }
});
```

Even if from the `$watch` the value is `false` but previously I checked it the checkbox remains checked. How can I uncheck that checkbox with AngularJS?

Comment: So when you check it, you want it to uncheck after the save?

Comment: No, only if the value from SSE return false I wish to uncheck it, same if it return true and the checkbox is not checked... I wish it to be checked...

Comment: I may be having a moment but what is SSE? Is this one of your services that you are calling from within the `save` function?

Comment: SSE are Server Sent Events... Real time updates coming from API in my case. SSE send messages to the client allowing me to update values in real time similar to web sockets.

Comment: Ah right yes of course. Hmm. How are you hooking this into angular though? If using a data stream or sockets are you updating a controller variable in the callback of said stream?

Comment: Yes, SSE send updates to a service that I listen using `$watch`. The data return correctly but the checkbox is not updated assigning to his scope the updated Boolean value.

Comment: I wouldn't use `$watch` for this. For example; with say using `EventSource`, just update the `$scope` variable in the `onmessage` callback and this will update the view for you as intended.

Comment: I need to use a Service to propagate this and many other values to other Controllers.

Comment: You can put the functionality in a service yes. But, you don't need to use angulars `$http`. A service/factory is simply exposing functionality app wide. You could return a method to stop and start the stream and `onmessage` maybe broadcast the change to your controllers using `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it just adding a few more `ng` attributes to my input checkbox. It look like this now:

```
input(type='checkbox', ng-model='auto', ng-true-value='true', ng-false-value='false', ng-checked='auto', ng-change='save()')
```

`ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` solved my issue.

Now everything is working fine... (even if I still don't know why... lol)

Comment: this actually works fine for me too. I tried adding ng-checked and ng-model and tried to do all manipulations.

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="schedule_active" ng-true-value='true' ng-false-value='false' class="checkbox" id="schedule_active"/>

Answer (score 1):

try below checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="yourmodel" ng-true-value='true' ng-false-value='false' class="checkbox" id="schedule_active"/>
```

as answer is already provided, just to have quick copy paste for others, I've added above code.

Answer (score 0):

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked:

> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside
>   ngChecked is truthy.

Ng checked can take an expression. So maybe create a function that returns false from whatever events you need to take place?

```
input(type='checkbox', ng-model='auto', ng-checked='checkedFunction()', ng-change='save()')
```

and then your function

```
function checkedFunction()
{
   //do stuff
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't remove the checked value from the checkbox.